# a closed form solution to a combinatorial problem is needed

Tags: probability, combinatorics

for finding a probability I need to calculate $f(r)$ which is defined as:

\begin{equation}
f(r) = \sum_{k=r}^{N} \frac{(N-r+1)!}{(k-r)! (N-k)!}.
\end{equation}

for $N > r$. 
I'd very much appreciate if someone can help me in finding a closed form solution to the $f(r)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f\left(r\right)=\sum_{k=r}^{N}\frac{\left(N-r+1\right)!}{\left(k-r\right)!\left(N-k\right)!}=\left(N-r+1\right)\sum_{k=r}^{N}\binom{N-r}{k-r}=\left(N-r+1\right)\sum_{k=0}^{N-r}\binom{N-r}{k}1^{k}1^{N-r-k}=\left(N-r+1\right)\left(1+1\right)^{N-r}=\left(N-r+1\right)2^{N-r}$

Comment: thanks! will give +1 when I can.

Comment: seems like i could get voting permission pretty fast!

Comment: To be honest, I promoted that by upvoting your question.

Comment: ok, enjoyed having business with you, lol!

Comment: @Alex thanks for repairing.

Comment: You are welcome